# Probability that items chosen randomly are defective?

Tags: probability, self-study

6 light bulbs are chosen at random from 17 bulbs of which 6 are defective.

(a) What is the probability that exactly 2 are defective?

(b) What is the probability that at most 1 is defective?

Comment: This looks like standard bookwork. Please add the `self-study` tag and read its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)

Answer (score -1):

I believe the Hyper Geometric distribution can solve this problem.

My calculation for (a) is 0.399968